# Adding the same function to multiple buttons in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am trying to add the same button function to 2 different symbols in Flash. One is the logo and the other is text that I converted to a symbol that will show itself during the end scene.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, but I am extremely new to Actionscript & Flash.

My code looks like this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

myButton, txtButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.true.land"), "_blank"); 
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL
>   C:\Users\Angela\Desktop\ASU\GIT 314\Assignment
>   7\AngelaRogers_Assignment7.swf [SWF] C:\Users\Angela\Desktop\ASU\GIT
>   314\Assignment 7\AngelaRogers_Assignment7.swf - 351066 bytes after
>   decompression TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or
>   method of a null object reference.    at
>   Button/frame1()[Button::frame1:7]

Comment: try with no coma...`txtButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);` then `myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);` and you must have a myButton and txtButton elements available in the scene (make sure the movieclips are there and properly named) (otherwise you will have a null reference error (elements can't be found))) hth

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza That did not work. Now I am getting a duplicate definition error. My elements are available in the scene, that is not the issue.

Comment: If you're getting a duplicate definition error you're probably copying  the onClick function(`function onClick(e:MouseEvent)...`) (which you should, don't need to). you need to add the listener to different movie clips

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Sorry George, I really am very new to coding events so I don't understand what you are saying. I created a new line of code for the txtbutton and it still doesn't work.

Comment: well done for figuring out and good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You must write it twice - once for each button, starting with only it's name: `child.addEventListener`. There is no shortcut to add the same for two objects at once.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to create a shortcut that didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a shortcut function to do this easily enough.  (As pointed out by others, your comma is what is causing the error).  This I believe is more what you're after: (especially if you keep adding more buttons).

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

addClick(myButton, txtButton); //you can add as many items as you want as parameters

function addClick(...buttons):void {
    //the ...buttons parameter is known as the '...rest' parameter, and is an array of all the parameters passed to the function
    for each(var btn:Sprite in buttons){ //loop through all the items passed in and add the listener
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);
    }
}

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.true.land"), "_blank"); 
}
```